# how can I use class variables outside of a parsing statement wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, variables, xml-parsing, class-variables

I am parsing xml into variables  like so

```
void myClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
         if (e.Error == null)
            {
                XElement currencyElements = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

                XNamespace gesmes = "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01";
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

                usd=Convert.ToDouble(currencyElements.Descendants(ns +"Cube")
                .Where(x=>x.Attribute("currency")!=null)             
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("currency")
                .Value == "USD")
                .Select(x => new ClassRates
                {
                    usd=Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("rate").Value)  
                }));


            else
            {
                textBlock1.Text = e.Error.ToString();
            }
}
```

Here is my class ClassRates

```
public class ClassRates
        {
            public String curName { get; set; }
            public double curRate { get; set; }

            public double usd, jpy, bgn, czk, dkk, 
            gbp, huf, ltl, lvl, pln, ron, sek, chf, nok,
            hrk, rub, try1, aud, brl, cad, cny, hkd, idr, 
            ils, inr, krw, mxn, myr, nzd, php, sgd, thb, zar;
        }
```

the variable `usd` is not available outside of the parsing block for calculations. Is this because I'm selecting items through the class for parsing? Is there a work around?
Have tried to implement a dictionary/list/array for rates to be stored but also not working
,
here is the version where I try to use a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, double> rates = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                String xml = e.Result;
                XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
                XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
                XNamespace masterNs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

                doc.Element(ns.GetName("Envelope"))
                   .Element(masterNs.GetName("Cube"))
                   .Elements(masterNs.GetName("Cube"))
                   .ToList().ForEach(cube =>
                   {

                       var cubeCurrencies = cube.Descendants(masterNs.GetName("Cube"));

                       cubeCurrencies.ToList().ForEach(currency =>
                       {
                           var country = currency.Attribute("currency").Value;
                           var rate = currency.Attribute("rate").Value;

                           rates.Add(country, double.Parse(rate));
                       });

                   });
```

this results in a NullReferenceException which I can't find. Any thoughts welcome,

```
    <gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
  <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
  <Cube time="2012-04-12">
    <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3153"/>
    <Cube currency="JPY" rate="106.54"/>
    <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
    <Cube currency="CZK" rate="24.803"/>
    <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4384"/>
    <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.82470"/>
    <Cube currency="HUF" rate="296.90"/>
    <Cube currency="LTL" rate="3.4528"/>
    <Cube currency="LVL" rate="0.6989"/>
    <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.1802"/>
    <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.3745"/>
    <Cube currency="SEK" rate="8.8912"/>
    <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.2027"/>
    <Cube currency="NOK" rate="7.6100"/>
    <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.4758"/>
    <Cube currency="RUB" rate="38.7840"/>
    <Cube currency="TRY" rate="2.3664"/>
    <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.2645"/>
    <Cube currency="BRL" rate="2.4075"/>
    <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.3132"/>
    <Cube currency="CNY" rate="8.2961"/>
    <Cube currency="HKD" rate="10.2128"/>
    <Cube currency="IDR" rate="12055.30"/>
    <Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.9348"/>
    <Cube currency="INR" rate="67.8550"/>
    <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1500.58"/>
    <Cube currency="MXN" rate="17.2124"/>
    <Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.0360"/>
    <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.6001"/>
    <Cube currency="PHP" rate="56.176"/>
    <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.6507"/>
    <Cube currency="THB" rate="40.564"/>
    <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="10.4472"/>
</Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

mh

Comment: This code is so messed up, I don't even know where to begin... My friend, please don't get me wrong (I mean no disrespect) I think you need to understand Linq before starting to write code like this!

Comment: the parsing code? just going with examples and recommendations I've seen, cant find much on msdn for Linq, where can I find explanations on how to use it?

Comment: Does your xml map directly to your ClassRates object? If so, you may be able to directly deserialize it using xml serialization or datacontractserializer and simplify your life.

Comment: At the moment it doesn't but I had it that way in a previous attempt. not familiar with serialization or datacontractserializer but will have a look though

Comment: If you have control over your xml format this is the way to go IMHO. I'll try to get a sample up for you using twitter data today.

Comment: @earthling thanks looked at a twitter example previously but I think I'm hitting a wall because I need to use my parsed data for calculations rather than just display them.mh

Comment: you can still do calculations and add other methods/properties to your class. I'm only talking about a method to populate your ClassRates object

Answer (score 0):

Create a local instance of `ClassRate` in the `myClient_DownloadStringCompleted` and reference it instead of creating a new instance on Linq query completion.

Also, please refactor your parsing code, as well as `ClassRates`. Separate the Linq statements, create a parsing method that can take the currency type as a parameter and then perform the query based on that.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but I don't understand what you mean or how to implement/reference it it. is it like `ClassRates rates = new ClassRates();` sorry really struggling to understand it

Comment: Yes. Use it outside the scope of a query - instead, put it in the root of your event handler.

Comment: Ok but I dont understand how it helps or how to use the instance `rates`

Comment: it's a matter of scope. Right now you are defining your ClassRate instance inside the select method so the visibility is limited to inside there. If you declare it (`var rates = new ClassRates();`) on the first line of `myClient_DownloadstringCompleted` then you've increased the visibility (you'll also need to refer to the instance `rates` within the select method instead of `new ClassRate` like you have now)

Comment: I understand the idea of making it more visible but when I do this, should I use `rates.curName` for parsing?? As soon as I change `new ClassRates` to my instance `rates` I get errors all over the parsing code

Comment: errors all over? where and what errors? This seems odd since I only see one location where you would need to change to rates (and yes make sure you are using the instance name when accessing the properties). Could you post your xml?

Comment: is says that x does not exist in current context `currency.curName=x.Attribute("currency").Value,
                    currency.curRate=Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("rate").Value` will post xml above

Comment: Should I stick to simply assisgning variables or does the dictionary give me an advantage? providing I overcome current problem??

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Here's an example of two ways to deserialize an xml twitter feed. You will also need to have your classes set up and possibly decorate them with the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes.

Also if you have the time, look into json for your web services. It tends to have a much smaller footprint meaning less data sent across the wire than xml and it is easily deserialised.

```
    void myClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tweets = ReadToObject(e.Result);
        var tweets2 = ReadToObject2(e.Result);
    }

    private static statuses ReadToObject(string xml)
    {
        var tweets = new statuses();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(statuses));
            tweets = ser.ReadObject(ms) as statuses;
        }
        return tweets;

    }

    private static statuses ReadToObject2(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(statuses));
        var tweets = new statuses();

        using(var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                tweets = ser.Deserialize(xmlReader) as statuses;
            }
        }
        return tweets;
    }
```